# Understanding shared_ptr vis a vis bst

Tags: c++, c++11, c++14

I was trained in "C with Classes" style C++ and I need to rapidly get acclimated to modern C++.  I am writing a very simple bst with shared_ptr

```
 class bst
 {
 private:
     struct node
     {
         int data;
         shared_ptr<node> l, r;
     };
     shared_ptr<node> head;
     int size;


 public:
     bst() { size = 0; }
     shared_ptr<node> doinsert(shared_ptr<node> curr, int n)
     {
         if (curr.get() == nullptr)
         {
             curr.reset(new node);
             curr->data=n;
             size++;
         }
         else if (curr->data > n)
             curr->l.reset(doinsert(curr->l,n).get());
         else if (curr->data < n)
             curr->r.reset(doinsert(curr->r,n).get());
         return curr;
     }

     void insert(int n)
     {
         shared_ptr<node> temp = doinsert(head,n);
         head.reset(temp.get());
     }

     inline int getsize() { return size; }
 };
```

And I have a simple harness:

```
 int main()
 {
      vector<int> v = {2,1,1,2,3,1};
      bst temp;
      for(auto i : v) temp.insert(i);
 }
```

It looks like the first element gets inserted just fine but things go fubar after that. It wouldn't be resetting the pointer would it?

Comment: Why do you use shared_ptr? Use unique_ptr.

Comment: Is it just me or, when you use `shared_ptr` you should always have a call to `make_shared` to initialize the `shared_ptr` object correctly ?

Comment: @Vivick you can use new. You should use make_shared if you haven't a good reason to not do it.

Comment: What about case curr->data == n - are you ignoring duplicates be design or by mistake?

Comment: @ArtemyVysotsky this is by design, ignoring duplicates

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
     shared_ptr<node> temp = doinsert(head,n);
     head.reset(temp.get());
```

You get a naked pointer from a shared one and put it into another one. When temp gets deleted you have a dangling pointer in head. Instead do

```
head = doinsert(head,n);
```

Edit: added solution.

Comment: OK, yeah. I figured this was the case. So these should be unique_ptrs then?

Is there a good reference as to when to use the various types of smart pointers?

Comment: Use a shared_pointer whenever you want to share ownership. Use unique_ptr otherwise. But your problem is independent of this.

Comment: How would I fix this? Move temp into head?